# How do I reverse a mathematical infix expression in C?

Tags: c, queue, stack

I am trying to convert an infix expression into a prefix expression, that is from:

Input `~ 99+(88-77)*(66/(55-44)+33)`

to

Output `~  +  99  *  -  88  77  +  /  66  -  55  44  33`.

I have solved this test case but realised my code was erroneous because I had used the standard swap function to perform the reversal.
That is:

```
void swap (int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

However, I realised using this function meant that I am reversing the order within the number itself as well. That is 12 + 13 - 14 / 15 becomes 51 / 41 - 31 + 21, which is not what I want.

I have tried googling, and someone mentioned making use of a stack/queue to try to push the numbers in order. I understand how that works but I am awful at scanning input in C. I don't understand how I should scan and push the numbers and operators into my output string.

Thank you for reading my post and for any advice rendered.

Comment: The `swap` function you should will not change the order or digits, if you're storing those as actual integer values. Are you storing individual digits instead?

Comment: *"I understand how that works but I am awful at scanning input in C."* - If that's the case, then you could solve this for a hard coded string and then ask a question about input.

Comment: It probably works (as well as it does) using only single digit numbers... Maybe that is a clue... Maybe there's a difference between single character operators and multi-character values.

Comment: Thomas Jager Yes I am storing as individual chars because I am trying to reverse it into another string. It is also because the item in ListNode is specified as type char by the question if that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: It's hard to imagine why you even need a swap instruction in an infix-to-prefix conversion function.